# Convert a string to an array in vlang

Tags: vlang

I'm learning V, and as far as my attempts go, although a V string is an array of bytes, array methods are not applicable to strings. So I want to convert a string to an array. I have tried searching for this with no success, I found something in Go, but it's not usable in V:

```
[]byte("Here is a string....")
```

Is there any way to convert a string to an array in V?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`string.split(delim string)`](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/8650ec6916c44a119815950613c2159aecc9979f/vlib/builtin/string.v#L558) to just `array` and [`string.bytes()`](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/8650ec6916c44a119815950613c2159aecc9979f/vlib/builtin/string.v#L1675) for an `array` of `byte`s:

```
Welcome to the V REPL (for help with V itself, type `exit`, then run `v help`).
V 0.2.2 8650ec6
Use Ctrl-C or `exit` to exit, or `help` to see other available commands
>>> x := "test"
>>> x.split("")
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
>>> x.bytes()
[t, e, s, t]
```